# Text move in part of the screen. (And not from one end to the other)

Tags: html, css

I want it to move in a certain part on the x-axis, and not from side to side fully.

For example move only between div a and div b

What is the correct syntax for this?

```css
.holder {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.news {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: rightleft 20s linear infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.news.left {
  animation: leftright 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100vw, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="news left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you want to have it placed? post some html

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how the certain part is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set width to .holder

```css
.div{
    width:33.33%;
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .holder {
    overflow: hidden;    
  }

  .news {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .news.right{
    animation: rightleft 5s linear infinite;
  }
  .news.left {
    animation: leftright 5s linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rightleft {
    0% {
      transform: translate(200%, 0);
    }

    100% {
      transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
  }
  @keyframes leftright {
    0% {
      transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }

    100% {
      transform: translate(200%, 0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div holder">
  <div class="news right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
<div class="div"></div>
```